# JS - Most efficient way of running functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be off-topic, so forgive me if it is. I'm trying to optimize a site I'm working on which is quite JS / jQuery heavy.

This is how I'm triggering functions right now;

```
<a class="js-trigger" data-trigger-type="modal">Trigger a modal</a>
<a class="js-trigger" data-trigger-type="animation">Trigger an animation</a>
```

```js
$('.js-trigger').on('click', function() {
    var triggerType = $(this).data('trigger-type');
    if ( triggerType === 'modal' ) {
        sampleModalFunction();
    }
    else if ( triggerType === 'animation' ) {
        sampleAnimationFunction();
    }
});
```

It *seems* to be more efficient than running multiple `.on('click')` functions, but am I really causing more load time than I'm trying to save?

Comment: You're saving DOM operations on load at the cost of making the code more complex to read and maintain. For the tiny amount of performance to be gained by this approach, I'd say it's not worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @RoryMcCrossan could you expand on that please? How would this make it more difficult to read and/or maintain than say 10-15 different functions (This site is VERY heavy on JS)

Comment: You will have lots of `if` and `else if` statements. `if (a) { b(); ... c(); }` when you might mean `if (a) { b(); } c();`

Comment: If you have several thousand links you may want to switch to event delegation. If you only have a few links I don't think it matters.

Comment: To expand on the comments about readability. Something like this is much easier to humanly parse than a chain of if-statements. The performance difference isn't going to be very noticeable either.
https://jsfiddle.net/c3rddcjz/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="js-trigger" data-trigger-type="modal">Trigger a modal</a>
<a class="js-trigger" data-trigger-type="animation">Trigger an animation</a>


        $('.js-trigger').on('click', function() {
            if ( $(this).data('trigger-type') === 'modal' ) {
                sampleModalFunction();
            }
            else {
                sampleAnimationFunction();
            }
        });
```

Try not using extra variables also and else If conditions.

thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you're suggesting not to use extra variables?

Comment: You've changed the OP's functionality by dropping the last `else-if` he's theoretically going to have many of those and caching the `triggerType` in a variable will actually improve his performance (albeit, microscopically but it will).